# Why does PHP MySQL INSERT through AJAX call only happen sometimes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a page with a modal. The modal code is in its own PHP file called "tour-modal.php":

```
<div class="modal fade" id="tourModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="errors2"></div>
                <form class="tour-card" action="insert.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNameTourCard" placeholder="First Name"/>
                        <input id="middleInitialTour" type="hidden" value="">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastNameTourCard" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailTourCard"/>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneTourCard"/>
                        <select class="form-control" id="tourDate">
                            <option>May 25 2016</option>
                            <option>May 28 2016</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-control" id="tourTime">
                            <option>1:00 PM</option>
                            <option>1:30 PM</option>
                            <option>2:00 PM</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>  
                    <input id="tour-btn" type="button" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-default tour-button"/>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default tour-button" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On this same file, I have a jQuery/AJAX script like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery("#tour-btn").click(function (e) {
        var str = "firstNameTourCard=" + jQuery("#firstNameTourCard").val()
            + "&lastNameTourCard=" + jQuery("#lastNameTourCard").val()  
            + "&emailTourCard=" + jQuery("#emailTourCard").val()
            + "&phoneTourCard=" + jQuery("#phoneTourCard").val()
            + "&tourDate=" + jQuery("#tourDate").val()
            + "&tourTime=" + jQuery("#tourTime").val()
            + "&middleInitialTour=" + jQuery("#middleInitialTour").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/wp-content/themes/myTheme/tour-form.php",
            data: str,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success == 1) {
                    console.log ('success');
                    jQuery('#tourModal').modal('hide');
                } else {
                    console.log ('failure');
                    jQuery(".errors2").html(result.errors2);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Lastly, I have the "tour-form.php" file which is referenced in the AJAX call:

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MYDBNAME;charset=utf8',
                  'USERNAME',
                  'PASSWORD');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}

catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "did not connect...";
}


$firstNameTourCard = trim(isset($_POST['firstNameTourCard']) ? $_POST['firstNameTourCard'] : '');
$lastNameTourCard = trim(isset($_POST['lastNameTourCard']) ? $_POST['lastNameTourCard'] : '');
$emailTourCard = trim(isset($_POST['emailTourCard']) ? $_POST['emailTourCard'] : '');
$phoneTourCard = trim(isset($_POST['phoneTourCard']) ? $_POST['phoneTourCard'] : '');
$tourDate = trim(isset($_POST['tourDate']) ? $_POST['tourDate'] : '');
$tourTime = trim(isset($_POST['tourTime']) ? $_POST['tourTime'] : '');

if ($_POST['middleInitialTour'] != '') {
    $result = array(
    "success" => 1);
    die(json_encode($result));
}


$errors2 = Array();
if (sizeof($_POST) > 0) {
    if ($emailTourCard === '' || !filter_var($emailTourCard, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors2[] = '<span style="color:red;"> Please enter a valid email address. </span>';
    }
}

if (sizeof($errors2) > 0 || sizeof($_POST) == 0) {
    $result = array(
    "errors2" => implode("<br/>", $errors2),
    "success" => 0);
    die(json_encode($result));
}

$randID2 = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

$sql="INSERT INTO tours (id, first_name, last_name, email, phone, tour_date, tour_time, signup_date)
      VALUES
      ('".$randID2."', '".$firstNameTourCard."', '".$lastNameTourCard."', '".$emailTourCard."', '".$phoneTourCard."', '".$tourDate."', '".$tourTime."', NOW())";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();


$result = array(
    "success" => 1);
die(json_encode($result));

?>
```

The problem is that only 1 out of 5 times that I try this the SQL query actually executes. The AJAX call is called, and the PHP file sends a success over, the modal closes, but the `INSERT` statement is rare to actually work. Can anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs or viewed the browser's console when this happens?

Comment: Just add question code not POROJECT :-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard where can I?

Comment: F12 opens your browser's console and developer tools. Some errors will be reported there. Your logs will be on your webserver and the location is dependent upon the server type and OS.

Comment: @JayBlanchard is on the right track.  As a side-note from a programming standpoint, you should WATCH the PDO Execute, and use THAT to return success or failure.  Something like this: `$success = $sth->execute(); $result = array("success" => $success); ....` - so that the result "success" is accurate, as opposed to always "true"

Comment: So if $_POST['middleInitialTour'] is not empty, your PHP script returns success = 1, but the script never reachs the "INSERT INTO tours" section because die() kills the script. Is that what you want?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no errors in console

Comment: @Webomatik yes to weed out robots. It is supposed to stay blank

Comment: Don't use variable concatenation into SQL with PDO, use a prepared statement.

Comment: And use `$(".form-card").serialize()` to create the parameter string, instead of concatenating parameters yourself.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the lovely resource. Using everything you guys have given me, I've found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using material from almost every comment for my code, I went ahead and found my answer, only a few tweaks needed to be made. Thanks everybody!

The very end of "tour-form.php":

```
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
#success = $sth->execute();

$result = array(
"success" => $success);
die(json_encode($result));
```

New script:

```
jQuery("#tour-btn").click(function (e) {
    jQuery('#tour-btn').attr("disabled", true); 

    function joinTour(str) {
        jQuery.ajax({       
            type: "post",   
            url: "/wp-content/themes/myTheme/tour-form.php",
            data: str,  
            dataType: "json",   
            success: function(result) {         
                if (result.success == 1) {          
                    console.log ('success');        
                    jQuery('#tourModal').modal('hide');     
                    jQuery('#tour-btn').attr("disabled", false);     
                } else {    
                    console.log ('failure');    
                    if (result.errors2) {
                        jQuery(".errors2").html(result.errors2);    
                        jQuery('#tour-btn').attr("disabled", false);     
                    }
                    if (!result.errors2) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            joinTour(str);
                        }, 500)
                    }
                }       
            }   
        });
    }

    var str = $(form").serialize();

    joinTour(str);
});
```